# Add delay using ampscript or SSJS in cloud pages

Tags: ssjs, ampscript

Hi I'm trying to add delay withing cloud page using Ampscript / SSJS, is it even possible?

What im trying to accomplish is, Create a record in salescloud from the cloud page, wait for 5 seconds, then query the same record it will have a status updated and based on the status display different sections in my cloud page.

Comment: You'll get more visibility if you post your question on StackExchange.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud?sort=newest&pageSize=30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no server-side function in ampscript or SSJS to simulate a delay.

To accomplish this, I would recommend having 2 cloud pages, the 1st page would preform the Create record functionality and then redirect or call the 2nd landing page after 5 seconds.  The 5 second wait would need to occur client-side by either using javascript or meta tag.

Comment: Thanks @David Devoy, I will post the same question in salesforce stack exchange as well...Lets see...